# Is it possible to have an empty class inheriting attributes/operations from another?

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I currently have 4 classes, `User`, `Guest`, `Helper` and `Admin`: The `User` class defines the main attributes and operations that each subclass will have/be able to do. `Admin` has the most operations (highest access level). `Helper` has the second-highest access level, and `Guest` has the lowest.

My current problem is that since the `User` class defines every operation and attribute for the `Guest` class, the `Guest` class inherits everything and therefore on the UML class diagram it will appear empty if that makes sense. The `Helper` and `Admin` classes will have operations but no attributes since they inherit all the same attributes from the `User` class.

Is it possible to have an empty class that inherits everything from another class, as well as classes that have operations but no attributes since they are inherited from another class?

Edit: is it also possible to have the same attribute/operation in multiple classes?

Comment: Isn't there an attribute or method on your UML diagram that will indicate those operations/access levels??? If it's the case then that class can't be considered "empty" so it's fine

Comment: Theoretically that's ok. But what's the point in inherting everything an not altering any operation? You will have a dumb clone.

Comment: @qwerty_so, It can be very useful. You can use such empty classes as parameter types, to accept only instances of specific types. Suppose you have class 'Animal' with empty subclasses 'Horse' and 'Cow'. Class 'Farmer' has operations ride(h: Horse) and milk(c: Cow). Now, the farmer can only ride horses, not cows and he can only milk cows, not horses. This would not be possible if the subclasses were absent and were replaced by an attribute 'species' in class 'Animal'.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Let me think over that. Just for the fun: you CAN ride cows (not only done in rodeos) but you can also milk horses (if it's a mare).

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible in UML to have an empty class:  the UML syntax clarifies that a class may have `0..*` properties and operations.

If a class inherits from another one, it would automatically gets its properties and operations.  In this case, you should in principle not repeat  the inherited members.  If you nevertheless desire to visually remind them,  you can  precede them with a caret (`^`)

It is possible that the class inherits all its properties and operations and this appear as empty in the diagram

Comment: See my remark above.

Comment: @qwerty_so Oh!  Again a simultaneous posting! Same minute ;-)

Comment: Too late for an answer for me, so I just commented...

Comment: @qwerty_so I hesitated to discuss the design, in particular composition over inhertiance, and LSP.  But for me the OP narrative is too vague for in this regard